# Vapor 4: how to map an eagerly loaded parent relation into a different format?

Tags: swift, vapor, vapor-fluent

I am struggling a bit with how to return a model that contains a parent relationship, while mapping that eagerly loaded model into a different form.

Let's consider the following 2 models: `Course` and `User`.

```swift
final class Course: Model, Content {
  static let schema = "courses"

  @ID(key: .id)
  var id: UUID?

  @Field(key: "name")
  var name: String

  @Parent(key: "teacher_id")
  var teacher: User

  init() { }
}

final class User: Model, Content {
  static let schema = "users"

  @ID(key: .id)
  var id: UUID?

  @OptionalField(key: "avatar")
  var avatar: String?

  @Field(key: "name")
  var name: String

  @Field(key: "private")
  var somePrivateField: String

  init() { }
}
```

I have a route like this, which returns an array of courses:

```swift
func list(req: Request) throws -> EventLoopFuture<[Course]> {
  return Course
    .query(on: req.db)
    .all()
}
```

The resulting JSON looks something like this:

```json
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Course 1",
    "teacher": {
      "id": 1
    }
]
```

What I want instead is that the teacher object is returned, which is easy enough by adding `.with(\.$teacher)` to the query. Vapor 4 does make this very easy!

```json
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Course 1",
    "teacher": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "User 1",
      "avatar": "https://www.example.com/avatar.jpg",
      "somePrivateField": "super secret internal info"
    }
]
```

And there's my problem: the entire `User` object is returned, with literally all fields, even ones I don't want to make public.

What is the easiest way to transform the teacher info a different version of the `User` model, like `PublicUser`? Does that mean I have to make a DTO for the `Course`, map my array from `[Course]` to `[PublicCourse]`, copy all properties, keep them in sync when the `Course` model changes, etc?

That seems like a lot of boilerplate with lots of room for mistakes in the future. Would love to hear if there are better options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by first encoding the original model and then decoding it into a structure with fewer fields. So, for an instance of `Course` stored in `course` to convert to `PublicCourse` you would do:

```swift
struct PublicCourse: Decodable {
    //...
    let teacher: PublicUser
    //...
}

let course:Course = // result of Course.query including `with(\.$teacher)`
let encoder = JSONEncoder()
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let data = try encoder.encode(course)
let publicCourse = try decoder.decode(PublicCourse.self, from: data)
```

Notice the `PublicUser` field in the structure. If this is the cut-down version, you can generate your minimal JSON in one go.

Comment: Isn't this pretty bad performance-wise? And sadly it doesn't solve the problem of having to create a PublicCourse and PublicUser model, copy/paste all the properties, and make sure not to forget to add newly added properties, etc. I wish Vapor had an easier way of determining subsets of fields for JSON output.

Comment: You're always going to have to specify the subset of fields explicitly or you risk introducing leaks by default and the inclusion of a new field (or not) in the public structure achieves this control measure. Unless the private version is huge, it's not a massive overhead and I haven't experienced any problems with performance. I tried using a protocol and conforming both to it and it might be possible to do something with Mirror but I doubt there's big performance difference and it seemed overly complex.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, what about this approach? Create a second `Model`, called `Teacher`, say, that is defined as the subset of fields from `User` that you want to expose in your API/JSON and has the same schema/table name as `User`:

```swift
final class Teacher: Model, Content {
  static let schema = "users"

  // public fields
}
```

Then change your relation in `Course` to:

```swift
@Parent(key: "teacher_id")
var teacher: Teacher
```

Your original query will work unchanged, but just returning the reduced field-set. It will work certainly if you are using `Teacher` read-only. No need to create `Migrations` for `Teacher` as the underlying table exists. I can't see a way to avoid including the ID, but that may not be a problem.

Comment: Interesting! I'm going to look into this, thanks for the idea.

Comment: @KevinRenskers, did it do what you want?

Comment: I haven't tried it yet, I'm going to work on my side project in the weekend again.

Comment: In the end I went with the other approach, it feels safer wrt doing updates and creates.