# Vapor 4: how to include siblings including extra properties from the pivot table?

Tags: swift, vapor, vapor-fluent

I am struggling a lot with how to return a model that contains a many-to-many relationship via a pivot table that contains extra fields. Basically, I want to return the full pivot table with the extra fields, but I can't figure how to do this.

Let's consider the following 3 models: `Course`, `User`, and the pivot between them, a `Student`. The `Student` model contains the extra field `progress`.

```swift
final class Course: Model, Content {
  static let schema = "courses"

  @ID(key: .id)
  var id: UUID?

  @Field(key: "name")
  var name: String

  init() { }
}

final class Student: Model {
  static let schema = "students"

  @ID(key: .id)
  var id: UUID?

  @Parent(key: "course_id")
  var course: Course

  @Parent(key: "user_id")
  var user: User

  @Field(key: "progress")
  var progress: Int

  init() { }
}

final class User: Model, Content {
  static let schema = "users"

  @ID(key: .id)
  var id: UUID?

  @Field(key: "name")
  var name: String

  @Field(key: "private")
  var somePrivateField: String

  init() { }
}
```

I have a route like this, which returns an array of courses:

```swift
func list(req: Request) throws -> EventLoopFuture<[Course]> {
  return Course
    .query(on: req.db)
    .all()
    .get()
}
```

The resulting JSON looks something like this:

```json
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Course 1"
  }
]
```

How can I also include the array of students, so that the end result is something like this?

```json
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Course 1",
    "students": [
      {
        "user": {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "User 1"
        },
        "progress": 0
      },
      {
        "user": {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "User 2"
        },
        "progress": 100
      },
    ]
]
```

I can add the users to the `Course` model like this:

```swift
@Siblings(through: Student.self, from: \.$course, to: \.$user)
public var users: [User]
```

And then change my route like this:

```swift
func list(req: Request) throws -> EventLoopFuture<[Course]> {
  return Course
    .query(on: req.db)
    .with(\.$user)
    .all()
    .get()
}
```

But that only adds the user info to the result, NOT the extra properties on the pivot table (namely, `progress`). It kinda seems to me that even though pivot tables can have extra properties and the docs even specifically point that out, there are no good ways of actually dealing with this scenario since `@Siblings` don't point to the pivot at all.

Bonus question: I'd want the `User` model be mapped to a `PublicUser` model, so that private/internal fields are not part of the JSON result. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68414706/vapor-4-how-to-map-an-eagerly-loaded-parent-relation-into-a-different-format) for what I mean. I want to do that same thing, but with the Student pivot's User model. Complicated, I know

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I encountered the same issue about accessing additional fields in the pivot table, but there is a fairly tidy way of accomplishing this. In addition to your siblings relationship, define a `@Children` relation from `Course` to `Student`. Then, in your query, do a nested `with`.

Put this in your Course model:

```swift
@Children(for:\.$course) var students: [Student]
```

Query:

```swift
let query = Course.query(on: req.db).with(\.$students){ $0.with(\.$user) }.all()
```

The first `with` gets the additional fields of the pivot table and then the nested `with` get the `User` model.

Answer (score 2):

You can query and use the extra properties on the pivot table directly using the `pivots` property on the `Sibling` relation which eagerly loads the pivot table objects through the sibling relation for easy access.

Eg:

```
Course.query(on: db)
.with(\.$user)
.with(\.$user.$pivots).all().map { course in
     // you can now access the loaded students using:
     let students = course.$user.pivots
     ...
}
```