# Returning specific field in vapor4

Tags: fluent, vapor

I don't want to get the `location` field, but return the other fields. How would I make it happen?

```swift
    func getperinfo(_ req: Request) throws -> EventLoopFuture<[Info]>{
          
             let user = try req.auth.require(User.self)
    
            return Info.query(on: req.db).filter(\.$user.$id == user.id!).all()
        }
```

Model:

```swift
    import Foundation
    import Fluent
    import Vapor
    import FluentPostgresDriver
    import FluentPostGIS
    
    final class Info:Model,Content{
        static let schema = "info"
        
        @ID(key: .id)
        var id:UUID?
        
        @Field(key: "姓名")
        var name: String
        
        @Field(key: "IG帳號")
        var account: String
        
        @Field(key: "頭像")
        var picture: String
        
        @Field(key: "年紀")
        var age: String
        
        @Field(key: "生日")
        var birth: String
        
        @Field(key: "居住城市")
        var city: String
        
        @Field(key: "興趣")
        var hobby : String
        
        @Field(key:"位置")
        var location: GeometricPoint2D
        
        @Parent(key: "user_id")
        var user: User
    
        init(){}
        
        init(id:UUID?=nil, name:String, account:String, picture:String ,age:String, birth:String,location: GeometricPoint2D , city:String, hobby:String, userId:UUID){
            self.id=id
            self.name=name
            self.account=account
            self.picture=picture
            self.age=age
            self.birth=birth
            self.location=location
            self.city=city
            self.hobby=hobby
            self.$user.id=userId
        }
    }
```

Comment: See my accepted answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68414706/vapor-4-how-to-map-an-eagerly-loaded-parent-relation-into-a-different-format It is the same idea, create the 'public' version of the structure without `location`.

Comment: And I tried your function. It works fine this time. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just could create a new struct with less fields and then map results into it

```swift
struct MyCustomResult: Content {
    let id: UUID
    let name: String
}

func getperinfo(_ req: Request) throws -> EventLoopFuture<[MyCustomResult]>{
    let user = try req.auth.require(User.self)
    return Info.query(on: req.db).filter(\.$user.$id == user.id!).all().map {
        $0.map { MyCustomResult(id: $0.id!, name: $0.name) }
    }
}
```